# How to write global function for server error and success in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, server, global

I have a separate functions like, submit,update,delete. for all function

```
$http[method](url)
   .then(function(response) {
           $scope.successMessage = true;
} , function(response) {
          $scope.errorMessageWrong=true;
});
```

**html**

```
<p ng-show="successMessage">Success</p>
<p ng-show="errorMessageWrong"> Something went wrong </p>
```

For separate functionalities. i need to show the corresponding messages. but i don't want to repeat the code for update, delete and submit and even the same thing for the other pages which do the same operation.
how to create function called errorHandler or something. so that i can  reuse it. 
can anyone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to create function called `errorHandler` or something. so that i can reuse it.

Create **chainable** promises by **returning** for fulfilled data responses and **throwing** rejected error responses.

The example function below takes an httpPromise as an argument, puts success or error messages on $scope, and returns a promise suitable for chaining.

```
function errorHandler(httpPromise) {
    var derivedPromise = httpPromise
       .then(function onFulfilled(response) {
                 $scope.successMessage = true;
                 //return response for chaining
                 return response;
            },
            function onRejected(errorResponse) {
                 $scope.errorMessageWrong = true;
                 //throw error to chain rejection
                 throw errorResponse;
            });
    //return derivedPromise for chaining
    return derivedResponse;
};
```

Then in client code:

```
var httpPromise = $http[method](url);

errorHandler(httpPromise).then( function (response) {
    //use data
});
```

The client code saves the httpPromise from the `$http` service call, processes the promise with the `errorHandler` function, and the uses the derived promise returned by the `errorHandler` function.

Because calling the `then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you want it global to your app, then you can use an httpInterceptor.

You have to create an interceptor service and then add the interceptor to the $httpProvider in your app.config().

Create your interceptor service:

```
angular.module('app').factory('myInterceptorService', myInterceptorService);

function myInterceptorService($q){
   var errorMessage;
   var bShowHideWatchFlag;
   return{
       requestError:  requestError,
       responseError:  responseError,
       showFlag: bShowFlag,
       errorMessage: errorMessage
  };
  function requestError(rejection){
       errorMesasge = 'Request error';
       bShowHideWatchFlag = true;
       $q.reject(rejection);
       return;
  }
  function responseError(rejection){
       errorMesasge = 'Response error';
       bShowHideWatchFlag = true;
       $q.reject(rejection);
       return;
  }
}
```

To register with app config, add $httpProvider to app.config

```
app.config([...,'$httpProvider'...){
    $httpProvider.interceptor.push('myInterceptorService');
}
```

In your controller, you have to bind a watch to the service showFlag:

```
  $scope.$watch( function () { return myInterceptorService.showFlag; },        
    function (oldval,newval) {
       if( oldval!=newval){
            $scope.errorMessage = myInterceptorService.errroMessage;
            $scope.showMessage  = newval;
        }
}, true);
```

Comment: I got this error in console `Error: [$injector:undef] Provider 'myInterceptorService' must return a value from $get factory method.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use service for this and share within various controller. $http is also a service. But if you want to add something more to the data you can create a new service and inject $http to it.